# Angularjs min max date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to Set min-max of dates dynamically in angularjs. I mean if I set the min date in angularjs it should be binded automatically to frontend.

 
this is what i wrote in my controller
$scope.from1date='2016-12-31';
        $scope.to1date='2016-12-31';
Whenver I change my min date in my controller it should be reflected in my frontendpage and how to do that...

Comment: <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="from1date" min="{{to1date}}">
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="to1date" max="{{from1date}}">and in my controller $scope.from1date='2016-12-31';
        $scope.to1date='2016-12-31';

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me. Have you taken a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp) on angularjs controllers from W3Schools? I'm guessing your overall logic might somehow be wrong/buggy. Particularly, [this code snippet](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller) from the tutorial is exactly what you need for the formatting (you could even copy-paste it to your source code) and put your exact code you provided in the comment of your post in it. Then you might notice where you've gone wrong.

I hope this helps – let me know how it goes!

EDIT: I see, here's where you went wrong. You need to use a Date object (see [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in the MDN Docs).

Simply, something like this should do it:

```
$scope.from1date= new Date(2015, 12, 20); //'2016-12-20';
$scope.to1date= new Date(2015, 12, 31); //'2016-12-31';
```

Comment: hi bro.... for ng-model its works but I want to bind min-max dates if u know how to do that please lemme know

Comment: hey, I see. Sorry, misread your original question. I updated my answer. Let me know if there are any issues and hope this helps!

Comment: Did that help? Let me know if not. If this is what you were looking for, feel free to mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to give you simple example. Hope this helps. If this doesn't work, do let me know the specifics to check it further. I have fixed one date and the other using system day for a better example.

Controller code

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.minDate = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
        $scope.maxDate = new Date();
    });
```

HTML code

I have added date filter in one of the text box. You can add date filters as required.

```
 <head>
        <title></title>    
        <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/DateTest.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            Min Date: <input type="text" ng-model="minDate | date: medium"><br>
            Max Date: <input type="text" ng-model="maxDate"><br>
            <br>        

        </div>

    </body>
```

[image: The result appears as follows]

Comment: Do let me know if the above solution works. Glad to help if more details required

Comment: If the above solution helps, please accept the answer or do let me know where you have got struck